# SLURM: parallel array jobs with consecutive run

Tags: arrays, jobs, slurm, parallels, sbatch

I want to perform similar (parallel) runs with job arrays with SLURM, by submitting a unique job. When a single task is finished, I want to start a second run that takes in iput a file produced by the first task. Is it possible? I make an example.

I want to run 3 parallel tasks, with  `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID=0,1,2`.
When a single task is finished, e.g. `srun ./my_program1.exe 0` is finished, I want to start `srun ./my_program2.exe 0 < input_from_myprogram1_taskid=0`, even if `srun ./my_program1.exe 1`is still running (each task could have a slighlty different execution time). Is it safe, does it make sense?

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=test_emb_arr
#SBATCH --output=res_emb_arr.txt
#
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --time=10:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=100
#
#SBATCH --array=0-2

srun ./my_program1.exe $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

###something that tells to the machine to wait until srun ./my_program1.exe $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is finished before make the following second run

srun ./my_program2.exe $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID < input_from_previous_single_run
```

Answer (score 0):

Should not the regular && be your solution here?
https://www.javatpoint.com/linux-double-ampersand

```
srun ./my_program1.exe $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID && srun ./my_program2.exe $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID < input_from_previous_single_run
```

Just to clarify, the double && makes the first one finish before starting the next.

Comment: the ampersand & makes you run parallel processes. I don't want it, since the second process needs the output from the first to run properly.

Comment: @fslack If you use two ampersand it waits for the first one to finish (see the link).